# Extend a ColdFusion 9 datasource file with ColdFusion 8 datasources

Tags: migration, datasource, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8

I'd like to merge the datasources from a ColdFusion 8 server to an existing ColdFusion 9 server. As far as I know the xml formats of the neo-datasources.xml of both versions are the same.

I've tried to copy and paste the xml block within the ... block from the CF8 neo-datasources.xml into the ColdFusion 9 xml file. Before that I've stopped the CF service.
But after restarting the service either the CF8 datasources are loaded or the CF9 ones. Mostly there are only the CF9 datasources remain and the CF8 xml nodes are getting stripped off.

Anyone can tell me a better way to extend the neo-datasources.xml with the datasources of the CF8 server?

There are more than a hundred and I do not want to set them up one by one. The server is a CF8 Pro/Standard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you come across Charlie's blog entry while searching for a solution? [Importing CF Admin settings in ANY release via "import wizard", even AFTER installation](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2014/11/11/import_cfadmin_settings_anytime_using_import_wizard) **Read to the end** I'm sure you don't want to migrate _ALL_ of the settings.

Comment: Thank you Miguel. I finally found Charlie's post after I solved it by writing a little tool that reads in the CF8 XML file, gets the connection and database data and uses the CF9 administration API to create an all new datasource in the CF9 server.

Answer (score 6):

I am answering my own question with a solution. Finally I discarded my plans to merge the CF8 into the CF9 neo-datasource.xml file. To set up the datasources in the CF9 server I found a way to use the CF9 administration API.

The steps are:

1. Read in the CF8 neo-datasource.xml
2. Convert it into a cfml array with structs holding the data
3. Initiate the CF9 administration API, logon and use the datasources.cfc to create every datasource as a new one at the CF9 server

Read in and convert the XML data:

```
<cfset wddx = fileRead(path_to_file) />
<cfwddx action="wddx2cfml" input="#wddx#" output="_array" validate="yes" />
```

This builds an array holding the structures with datasources information. We only need the first element of the array that holdes the datasource structures.

```
<cfset _str = _array[1] />
```

First log in to the cfadministrator:

```
<cfset admin = new cfide.adminapi.Administrator() />
<cfset login = admin.login("cf_admin_password_here", "admin") />
```

I used to sort the structure with "textnocase" to have the datasources sorted by name. So I'm looping over the StructKeyList() sorting it textnocase. This is because I am doing some output while running the loop. To do the output simply insert an output block with the "dsn"-structure data after the structure has been created. I've left it out in this post to save space.

```
<cfloop index="key" list="#ListSort(StructKeyList(str), 'textnocase')#">
    <cfset _str = str[key] />
    <cfset db = _str.name />
    <cfset dsn = {
            driver = 'mysql5',
            name = _str.name,
            host = 'localhost',
            port = '3306',
            database = TRIM(ReReplaceNoCase(_str.url, ".*\/(.+?)(\/?\?{0}|\/?\?{1}.*)$", "\1", "ALL")),
            username = 'db_user',
            password = 'db_password',
            args = 'useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8'
        }
    />
    <cfset dsnAPI = new cfide.adminapi.datasource() />
    <cfset dsnAPI.setMySQL5( argumentCollection = dsn ) />
</cfloop>
```

The database name is taken from the connection URL created by the MySQL 4/5 driver option in the datasources settings of the CF9 administrator.

```
TRIM(ReReplaceNoCase(_str.url, ".*\/(.+?)(\/?\?{0}|\/?\?{1}.*)$", "\1", "ALL"))
```

I think the "str" structure is self explanatory if you take a look at it using cfdump.

Hope this helps other ppl in their needs.

The core idea derived from Sean Walsh's blog at:

http://swalsh.org/blog/2013/03/20/programmatically-creating-new-datasource-in-coldfusion/

Thank you very much, Sean.

Comment: Upvote for a programmatic approach to solve your issue. Well done!